# Subvector spaces of $C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ which are stable by translations.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $E$ be the real vector space $C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ and for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let define $\tau_a\in\textrm{End}(E)$ by:
$$\tau_a(f):=f(\cdot+a).$$
Then, let $\Gamma$ be the subset $\{\tau_a;a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of $\textrm{End}(E)$.

I am interested in a characterization of the subvector spaces $F$ of $E$ which are stable by $\Gamma$, namely:
$$\forall a\in\mathbb{R},\tau_a(F)\subseteq F.$$

In the finite-dimensional case, the problem is settled by the following:

> **Theorem.** If $F$ is finite-dimensional, then $F$ is stable by $\Gamma$ if and only if it is the set of solutions of a homogeneous constant-coefficients linear ordinary differential equation.

Naturally, my question concerns the infinite-dimensional case:

> Does a classification of infinite-dimensional $\Gamma$-stable subvector spaces of $E$ exists?

Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might ask this on MathOverflow as well since that's largely populated by professional mathematicians. I have a strong hunch your question leads to something like perturbation theory of linear operators, which that community may be better suited to help with.